# When I use OpenDNS, does it also block sites for others using my Windows internet connection?

Tags: windows, opendns

I created a wireless hotspot in Windows 7 using the following method, without using a software like Connectify:

[Lifehacker — Turn Your Windows 7 PC Into a Wireless Hotspot](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot)

I'm using OpenDNS on the machine. If I let users connect to the network I've created, will the sites being blocked on my machine also be blocked on their machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what addresses your DHCP server is handing out.  If it's handing out the same addresses as the OpenDNS name servers, then yes (unless others change their DNS settings manually).

Comment: I think the main concern is that anybody can circumvent the blocking by just using another DNS provider.

Comment: If it is their machine and they have admin privileges on it, then it's not too difficult under any operating system to for that person to specify using a different DNS server than what a DHCP server hands out.  If you're letting users connect to your network, then nine times out of then you have a DHCP server handing out addresses.  Windows Internet Connection Sharing has a limited one built-in.